# How do i fix this comparative box plot in ggplot2 (R)?

Tags: r, ggplot2

The code i have used is:

```
library(ggplot2)
read.csv("broadbanddata.csv")
ggplot(broadband) + geom_boxplot(aes(x = rsp, y = Busy.hour.trimmed.mean.download.speed))
```

but it just comes up with a bunch of squiggly lines

[image: photo of graph error]

Comment: Welcome to SO! It would be easier to help you if you provide [a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) including a snippet of your data or some fake data.

Comment: This said: From your image I would guess that you `Busy.hour.trimmed.mean.download.speed` column isn't a numeric. To fix that try with `as.numeric(Busy.hour.trimmed.mean.download.speed)`.